# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style' / can't update

Tags: python, matplotlib, version, python-module

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'**

I am trying to use the style method from the matplotlib module but, I get this error

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'`

After searching I found that styles were added in version 1.4 and I am on version 1.3.1 ,
so,I used

`pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

and know I should be on version 3.2.0 as the `pip list` and `pip freeze` say but, I still can't call the style function, and when I use this code

`import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)`

I get that I am still using version 1.3.1

I don't know how to apply the newer version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update the question with your code for calling the `style` method.

Comment: Try adding to your code at first - `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: @0buz - In this case its a question of how to upgrade from 1.3.1 which (presumably) doesn't have the function, so simply showing the code wouldn't help much.

Comment: Do you have more than one python installed? Try `which pip;which python` on linux, I think "where" on Windows to see if they are in the same distro.